# cloning rails git repo in aptana 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am trying to clone my rails git repo into aptana so I can work on it and also change between branches flawlessly. I have been using netbeans for the last few years, but now I would like to use aptana because it is more up to date.

I can not find a way to clone git repo in aptana and have all the branches available.

Would anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Aptana just performs a simple `git clone` operation, which means that all of your branches *are* available.  It's just that Aptana only shows you "local" branches (that is, branches that exist in the checked-out working copy on which Aptana is operating).  It doesn't appear, at least at first glance, that the GUI allows you to select remote branches...but you can do this without a problem on the command line.

Assujing that your Aptana project is in `~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 WOrkspace/MyProject`, you can do something like this...

- Change to the project directory.

  ```
  $ cd "~/Document/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/MyProject"
  ```
- Run `git branch -a` to see all available branches.  You'll see something like this:

  ```
  $ git branch -a
  * master
    remotes/origin/develop
    remotes/origin/master
    remotes/origin/nifty.feature
  ```
- Everything starting with `remotes/` is a remote branch.  You can create a local branch that tracks the remote branch with the `git checkout` command.  For example, to check out the `develop` branch:

  ```
  $ git checkout develop
  Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
  Switched to a new branch 'develop'
  ```

Return to Aptana Studio and you'll see the new branch listed in the popup menu by your project name.